# How can I run a meteor app and have it use the mup.json and settings.json file inside the staging folder?

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

When I run an app with 
meteor --settings staging/settings.json
it does not use the mongo database that is on staging/mup.json file

I have the following files in the staging folder:

```
mup.json
mupc.json
settings.json
```

Online I have read that the filename usually is mup.js but on the rep I have mup.son

How can I run the app with the database that is on the staging/mup.json file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the mup.json file is used to set the environment vars on the deploy server. It's not meant for running your app locally. In order to run the app locally and connect it to Mongo, you'll need to set the env var.

```
// Mac or Linux 
$ export MONGO_URL=mongodb://yourMongoURI

// Windows 
$ set MONGO_URL=mongodb://yourMongoURI
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your answer.
I was given access to a repo, the staging folder has the following files:
mup.json
mupc.json
settings.json

I must do some changes, how would you work on the app and test the changes?
I mean how you would run it, I need the data in the database to test the changes.

Comment: You need to find the mongo uri. It'll probably be in the mup.json file. After finding the mongo uri, you'll need to add it to the `MONGO_URL` environment variable as i showed in my answer. Then just run the app with `meteor`